# Return count of a table's column via pivot table Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have a `user` table, a `role` table and an intermediate table for those 2, `user_role`. It's a many-to-many relationship between the first 2 tables. 
I want to return the count of the users which have a specific role but I can't seem to get it right.

My migrations:

user:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
});
```

role:

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name', 40);
        $table->string('description', 255);
    });
```

user_role:

```
Schema::create('user_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('role_id');
    });
```

Relationship between them:

```
public function users(){ //in role model
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_role', 'role_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

public function roles(){ //in user model
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Role Seeder:

```
public function run()
    {
        Role::create([
            'id'            => 1,
            'name'          => 'Admin',
            'description'   => 'Admin User.'
        ]);
        Role::create([
            'id'            => 2,
            'name'          => 'Vendor',
            'description'   => 'Vendor User.'
        ]);
        Role::create([
            'id'            => 3,
            'name'          => 'User',
            'description'   => 'Simple User.'
        ]);
    }
```

in controller:

```
public function adminDashboard(){
        $users = User::all();
        return view('admin.dashboard')->withUsers($users);
    }
```

in view:

```
{{ $users->count() }}
```

This obviously, returns the total count of users in user table. Any ideas on how to return the count of users which have a specific role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$role->users()->count()`

To iterate over the roles and display the count of users, you can use this:

```
public function adminDashboard(){
    $roles = App\Role::all();
    return view('admin.dashboard', compact('roles'));
}
```

In your dashboard view:

```
@foreach ($roles as $role)
    <p>Role {{ $role->name }} has {{ $role->users()->count() }} users</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. It returns error: Method users does not exist.

Comment: But you mentioned you have a public function users() in your role model

Try: $role = Role::find(1); echo $role->users()->count()

Comment: You' re right. But still... Any thoughts why is that happening?

Comment: Open php artisan tinker. Type $role = App\Role::find(1); echo $role->users()->count()

Change the namespace of Role according to your app

Comment: The first command did return me some info:
`App\Role {#683
     id: 2,
     created_at: "2017-01-13 10:01:58",
     updated_at: "2017-01-13 10:01:58",
     name: "Vendor",
     description: "Vendor User.",
   }`

But the second one returned me: `3έΠΟ
=> null`

Comment: What was the second output again?

Comment: Try without the echo, just $role->users()->count()

Comment: Ok, so `$role->users()->count()` returns me: 1

Comment: There you go, it works. It says for role #2, there's only 1 user

Comment: Damn, finally. I got it to work. Thanks for your help! Now, if I want it to print these specified users to a table via `@foreach`, how would I do that?

Comment: I edited my answer for printing the user count using $foreach

Comment: I meant something like this: `@foreach ($users as $user)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $user->password }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach`

This will iterate all users, but to edit it to iterate only the users with the specified role

Comment: Oh then you can use your existing code, just say `view('admin.dashboard')->withUsers($role->users);`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!